# logical difference between pointers and references in Go and C++?

Tags: c++, go

> Regardless of provided convenience of references over pointers such as needleless of dereferencing and rules specific to use of each ,
>
> is there any logical reason to  provide two language constructs as pointers and references  or is it just a syntactic sugar?

(I guess the ultimate underlying implementation that compiler would use the same steps for references as do for pointers with implying/checking for rules defined for references by a language.)

*NOTE : the question is not about rules have defined by languages on references such as "references are not allowed to assign NULL in C++ but pointers" etc.*

Comment: In C++, a reference is an alias for an object. It goes well beyond syntactic sugar: it always refers to one and the same object, and it does not support pointer arithmetic.

Comment: This sounds like an interesting question, but I can't quite figure out what you're asking. How do Go and C++ play a role? What exact "difference" are you looking for? Could you please clarify the question?

Comment: @Kerrek Go and C++ have included to make the question to be specific hence allow to provide concrete answers.Further both languges have same semantics for refs and pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking two questions, if I understand correctly

1. What is the difference between pointers and references
2. Why support both data types

Here goes:

1. A pointer refers to a location in memory where a datatype resides. The size of a pointer is fixed, given the underlying hardware, generally 4 or 8 bytes - totally regardless of what it is in fact pointing to. Furthermore, a pointer can be passed to a function using an invalid value - `foo(reintepret_cast<int *>(0xDEADBEEF) );`. 
   In contrast, a reference ensures that the underlying data is valid - since the reference is an alias the the object itself and can't be moved from being so (providing the the referenced object is still in scope - *edited per remark below*).
2. There **are** reasons to support both types. The first reason is to ensure that data that is passed to functions is valid - without wasting cycles on testing pointer validity (not `NULL`). The second reason is that one can be sure that not only is the data pointing to a valid location, it is also pointing at a valid data object. But the main reason is that a reference allows us to enjoy the benefit of calling a function without passing arguments by value, yet still maintaining a guarantee that the argument refers to a valid value.

Comment: @levngli. Very constructive answers , many thanks for that. Would you be able to elloborate 'alias' concept as a part of this answer to make this answer futher valuable.

Comment: Sure, the meaning of alias is that the reference refers to the exact object. In other words, if you have an object such as `int foo` and a function with the signature `bar(int &rZog)` and you call `bar(foo)`, within `bar` - `rZog` and `foo` are the same. The ramification is that changes to `rZog` will be valid in `foo` after leaving `bar`. Should `bar` be implemented as `void bar(int &rZog) {rZog *= 2;}`; once called, `foo` itself will have been multiplied by 2.

Comment: "In contrast, a reference ensures that the underlying data is valid" Not true. If you have a reference to a variable that is then out of scope, it is no longer valid. If you pass that reference, it is still invalid.